# yandex-maps-jsapi

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, next.js, reactjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]я хочу создать совественный template для метки но у меня в ymaps, нету метод
ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass

```
 ymaps.ready(function (e) {
          var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.7, 37.6],
            zoom: 10,
            controls: []
          });

          console.log(ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass) // вот здесь undefined

          var squareLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="placemark_layout_container"><div class="square_layout">$</div></div>');

          var squarePlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
                  [55.725118, 37.682145], {
                    hintContent: 'Placemark with a rectangular HTML layout'
                  }, {
                    iconLayout: squareLayout,
                    iconShape: {
                      type: 'Rectangle',
                    
                      coordinates: [
                        [-25, -25], [25, 25]
                      ]
                    }
                  }
          );
          map.geoObjects.add(squarePlacemark);
        }
```

Comment: Вам это подходит https://yandex.com/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark/ ?

Comment: Приведите полный пример файла или лучше соберите минимальный пример например в https://jsbin.com Быть может у вас подключение API с ошибками выполняется. В песочнице Яндекса ваш код (с добавлением забытой в конце кода скобки) выполняется без ошибок.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, да вы правы подключение API было не правильно